# Express Passportjs Google + Custom Authentication

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I have an express application where I'm using passportjs for managing authentication.

At the moment I only want to support sign in with google in my application. I have implemented this properly and is working fine. Now, I want to restrict access to to the application to only those users who are registered with the application.

Registration is done by admin so there can only be few users who are registered. At the moment, anyone with a google account is able to login to the application. Instead of this, I would like the authentication to happen with google using OAuth2.0 and I would like to check if the user exists in my database before letting the user login to the system.

**Update**

Following is my code as requested

```
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var config = require('./config');
var directoryService = require('./services/directory');

/**
 * Authentication configuration
 */
module.exports = function (app, router) {

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        //I want to know if this is the correct process
        directoryService.findResidentByEmailAddress(user.emails[0].value).then(function (data) {
            if (data == null || data.length == 0) {
                done({ 'status': 'Invalid Login' });
            } else {
                done(null, data);
            }

        });

    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
        done(null, obj);
    });

    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: config.auth.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.auth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.auth.callbackURL,
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
        function (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            process.nextTick(function () {
                return done(null, profile);
            });
        }
    ));

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    router.use(function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated() || req.url.startsWith('/auth/')) {
            return next();
        }
        res.redirect('/auth/login.html');
    });

    router.get('/auth/google',
        passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['email'] }));


    router.get('/auth/google/callback',
        passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
        function (req, res) {
            res.redirect('/');
        });

    router.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/auth/login.html');
    });
}
```

Comment: post your code so we can help.

Comment: Post something so we can help you better, we are not going to write whole code for you.

Comment: I am not looking for code.. I am looking for the idea on how to do it.. I will post the code in some time.. but it is exactly the same as what is there on passportjs documentation site.. as I mentioned there is nothing wrong with my code.. I want to add more functionality and looking for advise..